# Fetch image from database using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Unable to Load Image from database(Image is in byte[]) 
below is my code

```
  <div ng-app="MyProductApp">
        <h1>Category List</h1>
        <div ng-controller="ProductsController">
            <table>
                <tr ng-repeat="category in Category | orderBy : 'CategoryName'">
                    <td><a ng-click="redirectToProductWiseCategories($event)" id="{{category.CategoryID}}">{{category.CategoryName}}</a></td>
                    <td>
                        <img ng-src="data:image/JPEG;base64,{{category.Picture}}" alt="img" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Below is my Method, what am I doing wrong here please. Answers would be really appreciated. Thank you in advance

```
 <script>
        var app = angular.module("MyProductApp", []);
        app.controller("ProductsController", function ($scope, $http) {
            $http.get('/api/Products/GetAllCategories').
              success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                  //debugger;
                  $scope.Category = data;
              }).
              error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                  alert("erro");
              });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: any errors in console ? could you please make a plunker ?

Comment: no error in cconsole.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this,

```html
<div  ui-sref="task" class="col-lg-3 col-md-5 col-sm-6" ng-repeat="x in tasklist|filter:searchString">
    <div class="main-box clearfix profile-box">
   <div class="main-box-body clearfix">
  <div class="profile-box-header" padding-bottom:222px;">
  <img src="{{x.imageUrl}}"/>
    <div style=""></div>
  </div>
            <div class="profile-box-footer clearfix" >
    <span class="value" >  {{x.title}}</span>
    <span>{{x.description}}</span>
```

imageUrl is A field in Database, There i stored my images and retrive like this.